# Stay Signed in option for iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to implement a "Stay Signed in" or "Remember Me" check box to my iPhone app. How do I implement this? How do I store the user id?

Help is highly appreciated,

Thanks,
VKS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@VKS

- 1

  ```
  -(void)autologin:(id)sender
  {
      ischecked =!ischecked;
      UIButton *check = (UIButton*)sender;
      if(ischecked == NO)
          [check setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      else 
          [check setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-pressed.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  }
  ```
- 2

  ```
  if(ischecked == YES)
  {
      NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

      [standardUserDefaults setObject:mainDelegate.uName forKey:@"username"];
      [standardUserDefaults setObject:mainDelegate.uPassword forKey:@"password"];

      [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
  }
  ```

and for retrieving the password/username

- 3

  ```
  if(isChecked == YES)
  {
      NSUserDefaults *standard = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
      NSString *pass = [standard objectforkey:@"password"];
      NSString *user = [standard objectforkey:@"username"];
  }
  if ([pass == nil] || [user == nil])
  {
      // Show the alert view that user is not valid.
  }
  else 
  {
      // User is valid.
  }
  ```

Comment: Is it secured to store password in user defaults ?

Answer (score 4):

Since NSUserDefaults is not secure, i would recommend using iOS keychain to save password persistently.

look here: http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/using-keychain-to-store-username-and-password.html

Answer (score 1):

Check whether check box is checked and if checked then

```
         NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

        [standardUserDefaults setObject:mainDelegate.uName forKey:@"username"];
        [standardUserDefaults setObject:mainDelegate.uPassword forKey:@"password"];

        [standardUserDefaults synchronize];
```

This will save your variables and while login check for the saved NSUserDefaults.

```
      if (standardUserDefaults) {

         //Here check for the values if there are any values then use the same and login
        }
```

Check any NSUserDefaults tutorials on google, you will get the sample code.